# Simple C# event args question

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Im using WPF which has a `Storyboard` class that has a `Completed` event.

I use it like so:

```
sb.Completed += AddControlToTaskbar;

private void AddControlToTaskbar(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //...
}
```

How to I pass in the `EventArgs` to my method? Its always null, and I need it to be a custom class

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't pass the `EventArgs` to your method, the framework which dispatches the event does that. A common way to handle this is to wrap up your `AddControlToTaskbar` method in a class which stores the state, e.g.:

```
sb.Completed += new MyCustomClass(theStateYouNeedToStore).AddControlToTaskbar;
```

Your constructor stores the state.

```
class MyCustomClass<T> {
    private T state;
    public MyCustomClass(T state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public void AddControlToTaskbar(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        // Do what you need to do, you have access to your state via this.state.
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, and is the AddControlToTaskbar a public delegate of that class?

Comment: thanks for that... but the next thing I need to do is to make sure that after I run the `AddControlToTaskbar` method, I remove the handler from the Storyboard... how would I do that from the `AddControlToTaskbar` method in another class?

Comment: Pass it (`sb`) to your MyCustomClass constructor as well, then you have access to call whatever you want/need on it.

Comment: @nullptr Save's my time..Thansks a ton